# Most efficient method to randomly generate a location on some certain area?

Tags: java, optimization

I am working on a "greedy snake" game. I am using a 2d array to store the value of each location/grid of the map: either egg or snake body or empty. The egg needs to be generated on the empty spot. One solution could be:

```
while (new egg location overlaps snake body)
     Within the range of 2d array randomly generate an egg location
```

However when the snake grows very big and fills up most area of the map, the generating new egg become very inefficient, since it has to check almost every element of the 2d array. How can this be optimized?

Comment: How big is the grid, and how often do you need to generate a new egg?

Comment: Shouldn't you also avoid overlapping an existing egg?

Comment: Trying to write the AI so hopefully it can fill up the whole screen :) . The size can be something like 20 * 20, but doesn't really matter.

Comment: Make it work, make it work right, and then make it work fast. You'll probably find it that worst case O(n) really wont make any difference to your end user.

Comment: Thanks Rudi, I will just delete the "O(1)" from my question. But I still think the solution I mentioned above is very ugly. Do you know any optimization?

Comment: @assiegee - No problem. Posted an answer for your consideration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maintain a list of all empty squares. Every time you need a new random empty square use:

```
Collections.shuffle(list).get(0);
```

Comment: Pragmatic, but getting a random index between 0 and `list.size() - 1` would be less wasteful.

Comment: Or just shuffle them once and take the next one each time.

Comment: Thanks. May I ask your suggestion about how to store the coordinates in the list? Is there an easier way to convert the the index of the 2d array to the type of the list?

Comment: @assiegee - I'd use something like `class Point{int x; int y}`.

Comment: @BilltheLizard - That would be better - but if the list was modified on the fly the order would slowly become predictable.

Comment: I would think this solution is only more efficient near end game, and that maintaining and shuffling a list of empty squares when most of the grid spaces are empty would be a bit of a waste. It might be best to have this solution in place, but only start using it once the snake takes up greater than half of the grid.

Comment: @Rudi - It seems the [Fisher–Yates shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher-Yates_shuffle) is `O(n)` so not too bad.

Answer (score 1):

First, I would like to say that there is nothing wrong with your solution. The only issue you get is that late game (when most of the squares are taken up by the snake) you may have to try a large number of times to find an empty space.

In this situation OldCurmudgeon's solution is a good fit. However, it suffers from a different issue. Maintaining a list of empty squares from a large empty grid is a waste of time.

So early in the game, your current solution is preferable. But late game their solution is better.

So I would suggest doing a check on the size of the snake. If the snake takes up less than half of the grid use your current solution. Only when the snake takes up more than half of the grid start maintaining a list of empty squares.

Comment: There are probably efficiency calculations you could do to work out a more precise ratio for when it was best to switch to the second solution, but I have just said when the snake becomes half the size of the grid as an example.

Answer (score 0):

Give all the spaces the snake currently occupies as an input and then check from the remainder. Won't quite get to O(1) but will reduce how much of your array it needs to go through.

Comment: I am not sure how to "check from the remainder" when dealing with a 2d array. Thanks.

Comment: OldCurmudgeon's way is easier. In your question, you mentioned if( egg space overlaps snake body) so I thought you knew the snake body positions and could rule them out. In absence of that, the list of empty squares is essentially the same thing, but easier. Takes two lists though...

Answer (score 0):

```
public Point generateRandomPoint(){
    Random rand = new Random();
    Point p;
    boolean goodPoint = false;
    //while the point selected is not empty
    while (goodPoint!=true){
        p= new Point(rand.nextInt(MAX_X),rand.nextInt(MAX_Y));
        //is the point empty
        goodPoint = array[p.x][p.y].equals("empty");
    }

    return p;
}
```

If you use this, then it only checks the space that the egg would be spawned on.  Now, because it is random, it may have to check a lot of spaces, but unless your board is a couple thousand across, it should be almost instant (<<50 ms).